# C++ - Using multidimensional arrays with variable arguments in a header file

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I declare and define several variables that should be read and write by all the other files in my program in a header called "variables.h".

variables.h

```
const int N;
const int M;
extern double x[M][N]; // x position of the particles
extern double y[M][N]; // y position of the particles
const double dt; // Time step size in MD simulation
const double totalStep; // Total number of MD steps
```

variables.cpp

```
N = 30;
M = 2;
dt = 1e-10; // Time step size in MD simulation
totalStep = 1e+7; // Total number of MD steps
double x[M][N];
double y[M][N];
```

Then I use these variables in "calc.cpp" with header "calc.h" like this:

calc.cpp

```
#include "calc.h"
#include "variables.h"
void myCalculation(double x[][N], double y[][N]){
    for(int n = 0; n < M; n++){
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            double a; // This is just to show you guys
            double b;
            a = ( x[n][i+1] - x[n][i] );
            b = ( y[n][i+1] - y[n][i] );
        }
    }
}
```

calc.h

```
void myCalculation(double x[][N], double y[][N]);
```

However, at this point I get the error: "use of undeclared identifier N in calc.h", since N is not defined there. When I include "variables.h" in "calc.h", I get "redefinition of variables" error. I assume it is related to using a header in a header file somehow.

How can use my array in my function in the "calc.h"?

Comment: Add include guards or `#pragma once` to your headers.

Comment: Use `#define` instead of `const int`

Comment: rename to variables.cpp, and compile that file too (for the doubles/ints)

Comment: [OT]: your global `x`, `y` are hidden by parameters `x`, `y` in `myCalculation`. (and `x`, `y` are bad names for global variables).

Comment: @JonathanPotter I should do in variables.h : #define N 30 and then what should I do in calc.h? Do I need to include variables.h again there?

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you for pointing that out, I created another file called "variables.cpp" and instantiated x and y there. I understand that those are bad choices for being global variables, but from a physical point of view it makes sense, because there should only be one quantity that defines them and every function and calculation should use that one.

Comment: @melampyge: I would not use global `x`, `y`, but instead define them in `main` and pass them to the different functions (as `myCalculation`). (In fact I would use a `struct`/`class` to manage Particles)

Comment: @Jarod42 You're absolutely right; that's what I did in the first place indeed. I used classes to define Particles with properties such as x and y. But I'm doing a lot of lengthy calculations and the program looks horrible: cells[n].particles[i].x = ... like this, but it was at least working. I had to change everything to arrays, because my supervisor who needs to read and understand my code, so that he can help me with his insight in physics needs to read my code easily. Now I have to deal with this syntax nightmare.

Comment: @Jarod42 I can actually try to implement your other suggestion by defining x and y in main and passing them into functions from there on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order of declaration is not good, define `N`, `M` before `x`, `y`:

```
const int N = 30;
const int M = 2;
extern double x[M][N]; // x position of the particles
extern double y[M][N]; // y position of the particles
```

And any file using `N`, `M` should include `variables.h` as `calc.h`.

And your header should have [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

so

```
#ifndef VARIABLE_H
#define VARIABLE_H

// your code

#endif
```

or you may use `#pragma once` (but it is not standard :-( ).

Comment: Oh, this is why I get downvoted, I always screw up when I am trying to write a working example of the crash :). I am so sorry if I misled you but that's a mistake that I did when I translate my code here, in my original code it was correct. The problem appears to be that when I include variables.h in calc.h, the compiler says that there are 2 definitions for each variable.